# CXF org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Rejected by policy. (from client)

Tags: ssl, soap, ssl-certificate, cxf, x509certificate

I need to develop a SOAP client using CXF to call a webservice in a testing environment. I received from the webservice provider (an external agency) the test .P12 certificate.

This certificate hasn't been released from a CA.
I've added (only for testing purpose) the CA to the cacerts file.
But what I receive when send the message it's finally a response such this:

```
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {connection=[close], content-type=[text/xml], X-Backside-Transport=[FAIL FAIL]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Rejected by policy. (from client)</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

During the handshake I can see also this (activating javax.net.debug=ssl **I've replaced real CA details in log with some XXYY**):

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA256withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x2), SHA224withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=CA XYZ xyz Test, OU=XXYYXX xxyy, O=xxyy, C=XX>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
```

I've tried some solutions already posted on SO, but nothing seems it's working for me. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The SSL message means the server require a client certificate for two ways authentication, but it is optional to present one. You have not configured any suitable certificate of the required CA, then the handshake is succesful but it does not include identification. Probably the SOAP server expects a client certificate and fails when does not find it. You have to configure CXF to use your .p12 file for outbound https connections